# How to communicate with chrome extension background page in electron?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, electron

Since electron doesn't implement `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal`.
How can we communicate with chrome extension background page in main or renderer process?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, extension background page is one of webContents.

1. With `webContents.getAllWebContents()`, you could find all webContents.
2. And filter with `wc.getType() === 'backgroundPage'`.
3. Then load preload file.

You could do anything in the preload file.

```
  webContents.getAllWebContents().forEach((wc) => {
    if (wc.getType() === 'backgroundPage') {
      const preloadPath = path.join(__dirname, 'preloadForExtension.js');
      if (!wc.session.getPreloads().includes(preloadPath)) {
        wc.session.setPreloads(wc.session.getPreloads().concat(preloadPath));
      }
    }
  });
```